# How to change the rotation and scale of a text container by dragging in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, rotation, scale

I'm creating a Flutter app in which you can add text on images.
How can I change the rotation and scale of the text container by dragging their corresponding buttons?

[here is the text container's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NpvW.jpg)

and here is the text container's code:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: Icon(MdiIcons.close, size: 18),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: widget.onRotateButtonPanUpdate,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: Icon(MdiIcons.rotateRight, size: 18),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: Icon(MdiIcons.arrowExpand, size: 18),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(23.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        child: Text("Some Text"),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```